# How to create multiple beans (same type) in one Spring Boot java config class (@Configuration)?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In my yaml file, I have config values as below:

```
    myapp:
      rest-clients:
        rest-templates:
        - id: myService1
          username: chris
          password: li
          base-url: http://localhost:3000/service1
          read-timeout: 2s
          connect-timeout: 1s
        - id: myService2
          username: chris
          password: li
          base-url: http://localhost:3000/service1
          read-timeout: 2s
          connect-timeout: 1s
```

I want to Spring Boot 2 app register a RestTemplate for each config items.

My configuration is bean is below:

```java
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyAppRestClientsConfiguration {

    private MyAppRestClientsProperties properties;

    private GenericApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        properties.getRestTemplates().forEach(this::registerRestTemplate);
    }

    private void registerRestTemplate(MyAppRestTemplateConfig config) {
       // do some work
       applicationContext.registerBean(config.getId(), RestTemplate.class, () -> restTemplate) 
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I inject my registered RestTemplate via @Autowire, this config bean has not finished init yet. So there is no RestTemplate bean could be injected.

```java
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myService1")
    private RestTemplate client1;
```

```
The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=myService1)
```

Is there any correct way to implement this requirement?

Comment: Where do you inject your rest template.

Comment: You should try @DependsOn annotation. For more clarity refer https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html

Comment: @Thomas I inject my resttemplate in some controllers.

Comment: @P singh I am implmementing a lib for my team. So have no idea where other developers inject the resttmplate. I want them have the conf yaml, and then the resttempalte can be injected  in any beans, just like spring boot did for us. I dont want to force them use @DependsOn annotation when they want a resttemplate

Answer (score 3):

The problem with registering new beans in a `@PostConstruct` annotated method is that Spring is already past that particular point in the Spring life cycle ([more info on the Spring life cycle](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-core/spring-bean-life-cycle/)). Sometimes an annotation such as `@DependsOn` (already mentioned), `@Order`, or `@Lazy` might help. However, as you mentioned you'd rather not force (spring) implementation details upon projects that make use of your library, I've written a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` that registers a `RestTemplate` bean:

```java
@Component
public class DemoBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory configurableListableBeanFactory) {
        GenericBeanDefinition genericBeanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
        genericBeanDefinition.setBeanClass(RestTemplate.class);

        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        factory.setReadTimeout(Integer.valueOf(configurableListableBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue("${rest-templates[0].read-timeout}")));
        factory.setConnectTimeout(Integer.valueOf(configurableListableBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue("${rest-templates[0].connect-timeout}")));
        // etc

        ConstructorArgumentValues constructorArgumentValues = new ConstructorArgumentValues();
        constructorArgumentValues.addGenericArgumentValue(factory);

        genericBeanDefinition.setConstructorArgumentValues(constructorArgumentValues);

        String beanId = configurableListableBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue("${rest-templates[0].id}");
        ((DefaultListableBeanFactory) configurableListableBeanFactory).registerBeanDefinition(beanId, genericBeanDefinition);
    }
}
```

application.yml:

```
rest-templates:
  - id: myService1
    username: chris
    password: li
    base-url: http://localhost:3000/service1
    read-timeout: 2000
    connect-timeout: 1000
  - id: myService2
    username: chris
    password: li
    base-url: http://localhost:3000/service1
    read-timeout: 2000
    connect-timeout: 1000
```

Accompanying test:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myService1")
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void demoBeanFactoryPostProcessor_shouldRegisterBean() {
        String stackOverflow =
                restTemplate.getForObject("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57122343/how-to-create-multiple-beans-same-type-in-one-spring-boot-java-config-class", String.class);

        Assertions.assertThat(stackOverflow).contains("How to create multiple beans (same type) in one Spring Boot java config class (@Configuration)?");
    }

}
```

As the `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` is invoked before the application context is fully set up, I had to find a different way to retrieve the application properties. I used the method `ConfigurableListableBeanFactory#resolveEmbeddedValue` to retrieve placeholder values instead of having them injected by an `@Value` annotation or `environment#getProperty`. Furthermore, I rewrote the property value `2s` to `2000` as the `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` required an int value.

Comment: thank you for your answer. The issue for this solution is I have a `MyAppRestClientsProperties` which annotated by `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myapp.rest-clients")`. I still want to use the ConfigurationProperties feature provided by Spring Boot.

Comment: You can't. Binding of values from the environment to beans annotated by `@ConfigurationProperties` is done by [this `BeanPostProcesor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.html). Bean post-processors do their work after bean factory post-processors .

Answer (score 1):

You can levarage the binding mechanism that Spring Boot uses for the @ConfigurationPropeties. The corresponding beans can then be generated dynamically from a map of configurations

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor, EnvironmentAware {

  private Environment environment;

  @Override
  public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
      this.environment = environment;
  }

  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory configurableListableBeanFactory) {
      Binder.get(environment)
              .bind("com.example", FooMapProps.class)
              .get()
              .getMap()
              .forEach((name, props) -> configurableListableBeanFactory.registerSingleton(name + "FooService", new FooService(props.getGreeting())));
  }
}
```

In this way you can create multiple FooServices with different configurations based on your YAML config

```
com:
  example:
    map:
      hello:
        greeting: 'hello there!'
      hey:
        greeting: 'hey ho :)'
```

The corresponding properties class looks like this

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "com.example")
public class FooMapProps {

    private Map<String, FooProps> map;

    public Map<String, FooProps> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public void setMap(Map<String, FooProps> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public static class FooProps {

        private String greeting;

        public String getGreeting() {
            return greeting;
        }

        public void setGreeting(String greeting) {
            this.greeting= greeting;
        }
    }

}
```

In this example two FooService beans has been created with different greetings as constructor paramters. The beans can be accessed by the qualifiers 'helloFooService' and 'heyFooService'.